# Return list of strings which contain the keyword entered by the user in elastic search

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am looking for a type of search in elastic search which returns all the strings which contain a keyword. Following query only matches if the whole text is 'google' (case insensitive, so it also matches Google or GooGlE etc). How do I match for the 'google' inside of another string or even if I write 'goog'?

```
query: {
bool : {
    must: {
        match: { text: 'google'} 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I match for the 'google' inside of another string or even if I
>   write 'goog'?

[Wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) can help you find the sub-text you are looking for within a field.

In your case, it'll look like below. (It will return any documents where the text `goog` exists no matter what the pre and post text is for example: `this is google` OR `he is googling the answer`)

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "field_name": {
                "value": "*goog*",              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Baeldung has a tutorial on this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-tutorial, but below is how you retrieve data:

```
String articleTitle = "Spring Data Elasticsearch";
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
 .withQuery(matchQuery("title", articleTitle).minimumShouldMatch("75%"))
 .build();

List<Article> articles = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, Article.class);
```